# iMacros posts both COL1 & 2 in the same form input, commas are not working

Tags: csv

The following code logs into a Wordpress site and posts content (from Articles.csv) into two forms (title & post) and then submit the material and logs errors or sucess.

This is how my code looks:

```
Replaying #luikang.iim
1   VERSION BUILD=6050612 RECORDER=CR
2   
3   TAB T=1
4   
5   SET !DATASOURCE Articles.csv
6   SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 2
7   SET !LOOP 2
8   SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
9   SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
10  SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 2
11  
12  URL GOTO=http://luikang.se/wp-login.php
13  TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:loginform ATTR=ID:user_login CONTENT=Mother
14  SET !ENCRYPTION NO
15  TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=ID:loginform ATTR=ID:user_pass CONTENT=dfd92dkfgUud
16  TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:loginform ATTR=ID:wp-submit
17  WAIT SECONDS=1
18  TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:articleSubmit ATTR=NAME:title CONTENT={{!COL1}}
19  WAIT SECONDS=2
20  TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:post-html
21  WAIT SECONDS=1
22  TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:articleSubmit ATTR=ID:post CONTENT={{!COL2}}
23  WAIT SECONDS=1
24  TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:post-tmce
25  WAIT SECONDS=1
26  TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:articleSubmit ATTR=ID:cats[] CONTENT=%1
27  TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:articleSubmit ATTR=ID:submit
28  
29  TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:success EXTRACT=TXT
30  TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:error EXTRACT=TXT
31  SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=test1.csv
32  
33  TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Log<SP>out
```

This is how my .CSV looks:

```
First, Second
Hello my name is Lui Kang,"Can someone, please, tell me how to make Johnny Cage combos"
```

Everything works perfectly, but not my INPUT.

Running the code, iMacro posts the following 
**title**: Hello my name is Lui Kang,"Can someone, please, tell me how to make Johnny Cage combos"
**post**: undefined

If I change SET !LOOP 2 to SET !LOOP 1, it post the following:

**title**: First
**post**: Second

I need iMacro to post a sentence with commas, without this happening.

Should look like this:
**title**: Hello my name is Lui Kang
**post**: Can someone, please, tell me how to make Johnny Cage combos

wiki.imacros.net/Form_Filling says the following: Note: *Quotation marks are optional in most cases. They are only required if the value itself contains a comma, or a new line.*

What am I doing wrong?

Best regards,

Liu Kang

Comment: I "solved" this myself.

I opened Articles.csv in Notepad++, here I could see alot more quotation marks than within Microsoft Excel. 

I removed these, saved it and ran the script.

Can anyone tell me why Microsoft Excel did this.. to me?!

Works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this myself by opening the CSV file in Notepad++ instead of Excel, there were hidden quotation marks there. I removed them.

Comment: Yes, this can be the case. Also sometimes USA csv format uses , as delimiter and EU csv uses ; 
That can cause issues too.

Comment: Read about this too, Europe here, but my csv had commas, not semicolons.